# Button updates text of first element instead of selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

When I select the "Like" button, the button updates properly. However, the "like count" updates the count for the first image only, instead of the image I selected.

Any ideas how to make only the selected image's like count update as the button does?

Thank you in advance!

***html:***

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <img src="{{ photo.get_photo_url }}" />
    <input class="like_btn" photo="{{ photo.pk }}" value="{% if user.username in photo.get_likers %}Liked{% else %}Like{% endif %}" type="button" />
    <a href="#" id="like_count">0</a>
{% endfor %}
```

***jquery:***

```
$('.like_btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $like_btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'like_ajax' %}",
        data: {
            "photo_pk": $(this).attr("photo"),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.viewer_has_liked) {
                $like_btn.val("Liked");
                $('#like_count').html(data.like_count);
            } else {
                $like_btn.val("Like");
                $('#like_count').html(data.like_count);
            }
        },
        error: function (rs, e) {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every photo has the same id for its like count:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
    <a href="#" id="like_count">0</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Therefore, only the first is recognized as the 'real' `#like_count`

Since you have a primary key for the photo, you could make the ids distinct by incorporating the photo.pk:

```
<a href="#" id="like_count-{{ photo.pk }}">0</a>
```

**EDIT:**

Rather than changing the id for each like count, make it into a class and adjust the JavaScript. Try these changes:

In HTML, change this:

```
<a href="#" id="like_count">0</a>`
```

To this:

```
<a href="#" class="like_count">0</a>
```

In JavaScript, change this:

```
if (data.viewer_has_liked) {
    $like_btn.val("Liked");
    $('#like_count').html(data.like_count);
} else {
    $like_btn.val("Like");
    $('#like_count').html(data.like_count);
}
```

To this:

```
if (data.viewer_has_liked) {
    $like_btn.val("Liked");
    $like_btn.next('.like_count').html(data.like_count);
} else {
    $like_btn.val("Like");
    $like_btn.next('.like_count').html(data.like_count);
}
```

This changes will make the like counts a class (`.like_count`). Then in the JavaScript, you will choose the next selector (after `$like_btn`) that matches `.like_count`.

Comment: Would I need to update the jQuery as well? If so, how?

Comment: @jape: In the process of updating my answer to do just this! 5 minutes or less or your $$ back

Answer (score 0):

the `<a>` tags in loop have the same id which is conflict, so set an unique index in `<a>` tag property for jquery selector

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please give an example for me to compare with?

Comment: @jape: `<a href="#" id="like_count-{{ photo.pk }}">0</a>`

Comment: mfcovington's comment was available, also you have an other idea of get `<a>` with `$like_btn.parent().chlidren().find('a')`